# Capture previous GPU frame

Tags: ios, debugging, metal, gpu

In my `XCode` project I have a complicated algorithm which implemented on `GPU` via `Metal`. It's execution consists of few kernel functions so it's fair to say that it's a complicated pipeline.

It seems that my algorithm has a mistake somewhere which leads to having a bad data in the end. And I'm eager to know at what stage everything went wrong.

`XCode` has a GREAT tool for GPU Frame Capturing. But as far as I know, I can only capture next GPU frames, not previous ones. So my question is - is there a way to investigate GPU pipeline which failed with `GPU frame capture` tool? And if not, what option do I have here?

Comment: It's true that you can't retroactively capture frames with the GPU tools, but you can use `MTLCaptureManager` to [programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/frame_capture_debugging_tools/capturing_gpu_command_data_programmatically) "bracket" which GPU work you want to capture, meaning that you do have some control over which frame is captured as long as it's deterministic. If both manually capturing via Xcode and programmatically capturing fail, that's normally indicative of a bug in the tools layer, and you should file feedback.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your advice! `MTLCaptureManager` looks like an option for sure